# Fail to parse entry in bootstrap index maven sonar analysis with gitlab

Tags: maven, gitlab, sonarqube-scan

While running the sonar maven analysis I run into below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.1.1168:sonar
(default-cli) on project MFTGatewayService: Unable to execute
SonarQube: Fail to parse entry in bootstrap index: <!DOCTYPE
html><html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type"
content="text/html;
```

I am running this on GitLab and the analysis runs in a container. Project is on jdk 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow this issue was related to the gitlab yml file. It wasn't honoring the tokens when defined as variables for the job, instead I had to create variables in the job specific CI/CD pipeline and define the sonar token there. Post that things started working normally.